# Best way to create an auto-rotating "news" feed on a website?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

my client is asking for an auto-rotating news feed type thing on their site. The content will not change, but it will automatically move from item to the next. It will also allow the user to mouse over previous items and hold them in place.

This is best shown by the type of thing you find on Yahoo's homepage:

[image]

The four news items will auto-rotate, but when a user puts their mouse over one (as shown), it will stop rotating and just show that one, until they move it away (then it will continue auto-rotating).

I imagine I can do this with a lot of `$('item1').fade` and `$('item2').appear` type malarky using Prototype and Scriptaculous, but I was wondering if there was a better way, or an existing bit of code I could use (it seems like quite a common thing, these days).

Thanks for any tips or assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a little googling to find one but this looks exactly like your provided example:

http://www.agilecarousel.com/flavor_2.htm

Here are some other, simpler carousels that have been out in the wild for a little longer:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm

http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: +1 Ah! So these things are called Carousels! Thanks for the tip. Those links looks promising, too. That top one is exactly like my example, but unfortunately not too close to what I need to implement :) That's fine, though. This has definitely helped!

Comment: Yea, carousel is the magic term. I see now that the agile one does not continue autoscrolling on it's own - if I was smarter (or had more time) I'd hack the code and tell you how to add it :D I'm glad this helped.